# C# Snackbar as Dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, snackbar, material-design-in-xaml

I want to use the Snackbar from any thread. I declared my Snackbar as i should her;
https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Snackbar
The Wiki says that I can only access the Snackbar from a Dispatcher thread, but how do I implement this?

the user control xaml;

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost SnackbarMessageQueue="{Binding ElementName=MySnackbar, Path=MessageQueue}" Identifier="DialogSnackbar">
    <Grid>
        <!-- app content here -->
        <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="MySnackbar" MessageQueue="{materialDesign:MessageQueue}" />
    </Grid>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

to show a dialog, but i also want to hand over a message;
implementation from https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs

```
public static async void ShowDialog()
{
    var result = await DialogHost.Show("test", "DialogSnackbar", ExtendedOpenedEventHandler, ExtendedClosingEventHandler);
}

private static void ExtendedOpenedEventHandler(object sender, DialogOpenedEventArgs eventargs)
{
}         

private static void ExtendedClosingEventHandler(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
{         
}
```

the current message is displayed really weird

[image: current]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems to look right for me.

In your `ShowDialog()` method you only pass a string `"test"` as content for your `DialogHost` and you didn't define a `DataTemplate` in `DialogHost.DialogContentTemplate` nor a `DataTemplateSelector` in `DialogHost.DialogContentTemplateSelector`. So the default behavior of `ContentControl` kicks in when there is no `ContentTemplate` or `ContentTemplateSelector` defined and you don't pass the XAML elements directly as `Content`. This results in a `TextBlock` element being created for the dialog content where your string is bound to its `Text` property. This is exactly what your picture shows.

So to get a different result than what your picture shows you need to either pass directly your XAML elements which you want to show in your dialog (with a root container element and all buttons your dialog needs) or define a `DataTemplate` or `DataTemplateSelector` for your `DialogHost` in your XAML, if you want to use it in a MVVM scenario.

Look at this [example](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Dialogs.xaml) from the repo if you need a hint how you can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{

//Add the control related code stuff here

});
```

Answer (score -1):

with the help of @Anateus i get to this solution;

in my MainWindow.xaml i declared this;

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Identifier="DialogSnackbar">
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

The DialogSnackbarView.xaml - the content of the dialog;

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Grid>
        <materialDesign:Snackbar x:Name="MySnackbar"
                                 MessageQueue="{materialDesign:MessageQueue}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

to show the Dialog everywhere;

```
var view = new DialogSnackbarView();
view.MySnackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue("test");
await DialogHost.Show(view, "DialogSnackbar");
```

Comment: Anateus helped to find a solution, but you didn't award the bounty. Not very nice. You can't award you own answer and get reputation points back.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Next time I will reward the bounty. I didnt rewarded it because nobody gave me a real solution to my problem, only thougts...